# Undefined check in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, undefined

Is there a difference between doing

```
if(something === undefined) {
    //handle
}
```

and

```
if(typeof(something) === "undefined") {
    //handle
}
```

please? Which is better to use and why? Are there any risks involved?

Comment: It is generally considered better to use the 1st method from all I've read, which solves the issue of nulls if you do not use them and the double equals check. Has its own downsides though

Comment: Note that strict comparison `===` is not necessary in the second case, since `typeof` will always return string

Comment: Before ES5 you could change the value of `undefined`: `undefined = something; console.log(something === undefined) // -> true` With ES5 `undefined` [isn't writable anymore](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-undefined)